# How to figure out where the bugs are in a Django app

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% if page == "register" %}
<h1>Hello This is register Page!!!</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
  {% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
<p>Aready have an account <a href="{% url 'login' %}"> Login </a></p>
{% else %}
<div class="auth">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="auth__header text-center">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="{% static 'images/icon.svg' %}" alt="icon" />
      </a>
      <h3>Account Login</h3>
      <p>Hello Developer, Welcome Back!</p>
    </div>

    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST" class="form auth__form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <!-- Input:Email -->
      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="formInput#text">Username: </label>
        <input
          class="input input--text"
          id="formInput#text"
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Enter your username..."
        />
      </div>

      <!-- Input:Password -->
      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="formInput#password">Password: </label>
        <input
          class="input input--password"
          id="formInput#passowrd"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="••••••••"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="auth__actions">
        <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg" type="submit" value="Log In" />
        <a href="forgetpassword.html">Forget Password?</a>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="auth__alternative">
      <p>Don’t have an Account?</p>
      <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is my main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- Icon - IconMonster -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.iconmonstr.com/1.3.0/css/iconmonstr-iconic-font.min.css"
    />
    <!-- Mumble UI -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'uikit/styles/uikit.css' %}" />
    <!-- Dev Search UI -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/main.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'uikit/styles/app.css' %}" />

    <title>DevSearch - Connect with Developers!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'navbar.html' %} 
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% block content %} 
    {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I have been taking Udemy course "Learn to build awesome websites with Python & Django!" by Dennis Ivy and I have reached almost middle of the course but when I reached here I got stuck with these errors. How can I get rid of these errors?

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /login/
Invalid block tag on line 38: 'else', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 38: 'else', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: D:\Python\Django\devsearch\djenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 552, in invalid_block_tag
Python Executable:  D:\Python\Django\devsearch\djenv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.0
```

If I put `{% load static %}` above else block as below, it does work but I have to use inside if statement also, so when I do it as above, it gives error.

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}{% block content %}{% if page == 'register' %}
<h1>Hello This is register Page!!!</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
  {% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}}
  <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>

{% load static %} {% else %}
<div class="auth">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="auth__header text-center">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="{% static 'images/icon.svg' %}" alt="icon" />
      </a>
      <h3>Account Login</h3>
      <p>Hello Developer, Welcome Back!</p>
    </div>

    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST" class="form auth__form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <!-- Input:Email -->
      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="formInput#text">Username: </label>
        <input
          class="input input--text"
          id="formInput#text"
          type="text"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Enter your username..."
        />
      </div>

      <!-- Input:Password -->
      <div class="form__field">
        <label for="formInput#password">Password: </label>
        <input
          class="input input--password"
          id="formInput#passowrd"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="••••••••"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="auth__actions">
        <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg" type="submit" value="Log In" />
        <a href="forgetpassword.html">Forget Password?</a>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="auth__alternative">
      <p>Don’t have an Account?</p>
      <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %} {% endblock content %}
```

Here is my nave-bar.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!-- Header Section -->

<header class="header">
  <div class="container container--narrow">
    <a href="{% url 'profiles' %}" class="header__logo">
      <img src="{% static 'images/logo.svg' %}" alt="DevSearch Logo" />
    </a>
    <nav class="header__nav">
      <input type="checkbox" id="responsive-menu" />
      <label for="responsive-menu" class="toggle-menu">
        <span>Menu</span>
        <div class="toggle-menu__lines"></div>
      </label>
      <ul class="header__menu">
        <li class="header__menuItem">
          <a href="{% url 'profiles' %}">Developers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__menuItem">
          <a href="{% url 'projects' %}">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__menuItem"><a href="inbox.html">Inbox</a></li>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="header__menuItem">
          <a href="{% url 'create-project' %}">Add Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header__menuItem">
          <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn--sub">Log Out</a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="header__menuItem">
          <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn--sub">Login/Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you provide `main.html`? The error may not be in the template shown since the error mentions line 38 which doesn't seem to match what you have provided

Comment: Hello Sir,
I have added my main.html

Comment: The only other place it could be is `navbar.html`, check if there is an `else` block in it, could you provide it too?